# Async_read_until limit size of bytes read (Boost::asio)

Tags: c++, byte, boost-asio, limit

i want to know how can i limit the size of bytes to read with async_red_until .
From now i used it with a delimter character but i want to change.
Here is what i do :

```
void  Client::doRead()                                                                      
{                                                                                             
    boost::asio::async_read_until(m_socket,                                               
                                    m_buffer,                                             
                                    '\n',                                                 
                                  boost::bind(&Client::handleRead,                        
                                              shared_from_this(),                         
                                              boost::asio::placeholders::error));         
                                              }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `transfer_exactly` (https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/transfer_exactly.html)

Note that there is no guarantee you'll always read the amount, e.g. if the sending side closes the connection early. So check `bytes_transferred` as well as the `error_code`.

In many cases you can simply use `async_read` instead, with a a fixed buffer:

```
std::vector<char> m_buffer;

// ...
m_buffer.resize(24); // receive no more than 24 characters
boost::asio::async_read(m_socket, 
          boost::asio::buffer(m_buffer),                                             
          boost::bind(&Client::handleRead, shared_from_this(),                                               
          boost::asio::placeholders::error));
```

Comment: I get it but the size of my buffer is changing. What i want to do is that according to my protocol , i read one time to get tne nb of bytes i had to read next and then read exactly that size. I can't create a new buffer all the time because i have to handle that data in the function handler.

Comment: So, use the first option (`transfer_exactly`)